# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<?>[]

Tags: java, reflection, syntax-error

What does it mean, the following error message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<?>[]
```

The code is following:

```
            Class<?>[] encoderClass;
            Class<?>[] encoderClasses = new Class<?>[] {
                Encoder1.class,
                Encoder2.class,
                Encoder3.class
            };

            for(int i=0; i<encoderClasses.length; ++i) {
                encoderClass = encoderClasses[i]; // <------ error is here
            }
```

**UPDATE**

Oh, just silly mistake, thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to assign a single class element to a class array (different types as per the error message). Instead assign each individual element in the `for` loop

```
encoderClass[i] = encoderClasses[i];
```

ensuring that the array is initialized to avoid `NPE` in the assignment

```
Class<?>[] encoderClass = new Class<?>[3];
```

For simplicity you could replace the entire loop with

```
encoderClass = Arrays.copyOf(encoderClasses,  encoderClasses.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting array from Class.

You should change the following from:

```
Class<?>[] encoderClass;
```

To:

```
Class<?> encoderClass;
```